# Azure SQL Server Elastic query with ApplicationIntent ReadOnly

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I'm using SQL Server Management Studio v18.2* to create an Elastic Query to different Azure databases ([horizontal partitioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-query-overview)). The access to the databases must contain the flag `ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly`.

I've created the master key and the scoped credentials:

```
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'password'

CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL stg_credentials
WITH IDENTITY = 'user',
SECRET = 'pass';
```

And then, I need to create the [external data source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-external-data-source-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). According to the documentation, the syntax is:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE <data_source_name>  
WITH
(    LOCATION                  = '<prefix>://<path>[:<port>]'
[,   CONNECTION_OPTIONS        = '<name_value_pairs>']
[,   CREDENTIAL                = <credential_name> ]
[,   PUSHDOWN                  = ON | OFF]
[,   TYPE                      = HADOOP | BLOB_STORAGE ]
[,   RESOURCE_MANAGER_LOCATION = '<resource_manager>[:<port>]'
)
[;]
```

I'm using the following query:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE stg_1 WITH
    (TYPE = RDBMS, LOCATION = 'myserver.database.windows.net', CONNECTION_OPTIONS = 'ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly', DATABASE_NAME = 'mydatabase', CREDENTIAL = stg_credentials);
```

But when executing it, I get the following error, although I'm using the right [syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/applications/using-connection-string-keywords-with-sql-server-native-client?view=sql-server-2017) for that option.

> Incorrect syntax near 'CONNECTION_OPTIONS'.

Do I need to install any extra components to the SSMS? Is there anything wrong with the syntax? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

*
SQL Server Management Studio 15.0.18142.0
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools 15.0.1389.0
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC) 10.0.17763.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query across Azure SQL databases completely in T-SQL. This allows for **read-only** querying of remote databases and provides an option for current on-premises SQL Server customers to migrate applications using three- and four-part names or linked server to SQL DB.

And for Azure SQL database, it doesn't have the Argument "CONNECTION_OPTIONS".

[image]

You can find this from the document you have provided: [Azure SQL Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-external-data-source-transact-sql?view=azuresqldb-current#overview-azure-sql-database).

You also can reference this document [Get started with cross-database queries (vertical partitioning) (preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-query-getting-started-vertical#create-the-sample-databases). It also give the examples.

External data sources:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE MyElasticDBQueryDataSrc WITH
    (TYPE = RDBMS,
    LOCATION = '<server_name>.database.windows.net',
    DATABASE_NAME = 'Customers',
    CREDENTIAL = ElasticDBQueryCred,
) ;
```

**Update:**

[Elastic Query Preview limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-query-overview#preview-limitations):

> Elastic query works with Azure SQL Database only. You cannot use it for querying on-premises SQL Server, or SQL Server in a VM.

So you can not connect to a SQL Server on a virtual machine with Elastic Query.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for you answer Leon. The problem is that I'm not connecting to an Azure SQL Database, but to a SQL Server on a virtual machine. And I need to set that configuration parameter in the options.

Comment: @JaimeCaffarel Please see my update, that's the limitation of Elastic query.

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please install the latest version of SQL Server Management Studio ([v18.2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017)) for the best experience with all Azure SQL Database PaaS products.